# TSQL complex string manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named 'Title'. It stores Job titles ex: 'a java Developer' .
I want to create another table, Create keywords from titles and store all the keywords in it. I want to get rid of all special characters, some certain words like 'a' and 'the', break the string and store for example 'Java' and 'Developer' (Capitalize the first character)  in keywords table as two different records. How should i achieve this? What SQL functions are there to help me with this? any article or demo will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you need to use a delimiter splitter function. Split on space then you store the result into another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try something like this:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = ' senior java developer'

DECLARE @Final VARCHAR(50)

--Replace all the words you don't need
SELECT @Final = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(' ' , LTRIM(@test)), ' a ',''),' the ',  ''),' an ', '')))

;WITH cte_Replace AS
(
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@Final,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@Final,1) -1) AS Title,
    SUBSTRING(@Final,CHARINDEX(' ',@Final,1) +1, LEN(@Final) - CHARINDEX(' ',@Final,1) +1) AS RemainingString

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',RemainingString,1) != 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RemainingString,1,CHARINDEX(' ',RemainingString,1) -1) ELSE RemainingString END AS Title,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',RemainingString,1) != 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RemainingString,CHARINDEX(' ',RemainingString,1) +1, LEN(RemainingString) - CHARINDEX(' ',RemainingString,1) +1)  ELSE NULL END AS RemainingString
FROM 
    cte_Replace
where 
    RemainingString IS NOT  NULL
)
SELECT 
  UPPER(SUBSTRING(Title,1,1)) + SUBSTRING(Title,2,LEN(Title)-1) AS Title FROM cte_Replace
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
INSERT INTO KeyWord (keyword)
SELECT DISTNCT s.word
FROM   tbl t
CROSS APPLY dbo.SomeDelimiterSplitterFunction(t.Title, ' ') s
WHERE  t.word not in ('', 'a', 'the')
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but i how  my 'SomeDelimiterSplitterFunction' should looks like?